# Проверка результатов функции (процент от числа)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>>>
colors = {1 : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 96.9, 'Синий': 38.7},
          2 : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
          3 : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0}}

n = int(input("Какой номер цвета? :"))
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
new_color = {}

for key in colors[n]:
    print(key + ':', colors[n][key], '%')
print()
for s in colors.values():
   new_color.update(colors[n])

x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
def procent(**new_color):
    for key in new_color:
        print(key, "->", round(x * (new_color[key] / 100), 2)) # находим процент от 
числа

procent(**new_color)
>>>>







>>>>
Какой номер цвета? :1

Номер цвета: 1 C,U
Желтый: 3.1 %
Красный: 58.2 %
Синий: 38.7 %

Количество грамм краски?:567.3
Желтый -> 17.59
Красный -> 330.17
Синий -> 219.55
>>>>

Сумма всех цветов 567,31 отличается от заданной. Подскажите как устранить проблему?
```

Comment: А какие значения отличаются?

Comment: Если проблема с округлением, то правильное(математическое) округление можно сделать так: int(x * (new_color[key] / 100) + 0.5)

Comment: А +0.5 откуда взялось .Нужно точно чтоб было

Comment: При использовании int в качестве округления нужно прибавлять  0.5 к положительному числу, соответственно если отрицательное - то вычитать 0.5, так как int округляет к меньшему значению, в итоге, нехитрым образом, можно сделать грамотное (математическое) округление.

Comment: Если нужно, чтоб было точно, то не стоит вообще округлять)

Comment: Так float будет очень неточное . Может сложением результатов можно как то сделать?

Comment: Float-объект сам позволяет ввести десятичное число, следовательно при сложении с другим числом у вас может быть сумма дробным и большим. Попробуйте через round округлить до 4 значений после запятой(round(x * (new_color[key] / 100), 4)).

Comment: если сделать типа x = значение1+значение2+значение3 то будет хорошо работать, только не знаю как реализовать

Comment: Ну это же вопрос округления. Если вы хотите, чтобы точно сошлась до последнего знака сумма, то вам придётся "испортить" процент одного из чисел, он станет чуть менее правильным, ошибка будет тогда уже в проценте/весе одной из красок. Вы этого хотите?

Comment: да пусть будет это не проблема

Comment: Вот реализация того, что вы просили выше: Добавьте перед 'for key in new_color:' эту строку 'res = 0 # результирующая переменная', после 'for key in new_color:' содержимое в цикле исправьте на  'res += x * (new_color[key] / 100) # находим процент от числа'  и после цикла добавьте 'print(res)'

Comment: Могу указать полный код в качестве ответа на ваш вопрос.

Comment: напиши пожалуйста

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что помог и разъяснил)

Comment: Да спасибо большое получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения:

```
colors = {1 : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 96.9, 'Синий': 38.7},
          2 : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
          3 : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0}}

n = int(input("Какой номер цвета? :"))
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
new_color = {}

for key in colors[n]:
    print(key + ':', colors[n][key], '%')
print()
for s in colors.values():
   new_color.update(colors[n])

x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
def procent(**new_color):
    res = 0 # результирующая переменная
    for key in new_color:
        res += x * (new_color[key] / 100) # находим процент от числа
    print(res)

procent(**new_color)
```